# Diffucult graph task, can't figure out why my code is return wrong answer

Tags: c++, path, graph-theory

Recently I got this task

> For the third day, the defense of a strategically important field has been going on. And it has been announced that the enemy will perform a landing operation next night. The map of the field is conditionally divided into squares, and the average height of each square is known. According to the reports of scouts, the landing will be evenly distributed among all the squares.
>
> It was decided to construct trapdoors in some squares. When a trapdoor is placed in a square, all the landing troops that end up in that square fall into the trapdoor.
> Fortunately for the defenders, the entire field is currently covered in ice, and when the landing troops land on a square covered in ice, they slip and slide down the slope. Specifically, if it is possible to reach the trapdoor from the landing point by rolling over the borders of the squares without raising the height, all the landing troops from that landing point will slide into the trapdoors.
>
> It is required to determine the minimum number of trapdoors that need to be placed to catch all the landing troops after the landing.
>
> Input format:
> The input file begins with two integers N and M, which specify the dimensions of the map - natural numbers not exceeding 100. Next, there are N lines, each containing M numbers, which specify the height of the map squares. The height is a natural number not exceeding 10,000. It is assumed that the squares located outside the map have an infinitely large height (i.e., the landing troops will never reach there).
>
> Output format:
> Output the minimum number of trapdoors needed to catch all the landing troops.

I decided to start with adjacent matrix, where edge between two squares is exists if we can go from one square to another if they are neighboors, and we can reach square two without raising the height
Next, ChatGPT write for me function, that return all vertexes that we can reach from specified

This algorithm is called "breadth-first search (BFS)" or "breadth-first traversal". It starts from a given vertex, explores all the vertices at the same distance from the starting vertex before moving to the vertices that are farther away. In this implementation, it is used to find all the vertices that can be reached from a given target vertex in an undirected graph.

In main, I get all vertexes that we can get from zero vertex, add to vector "reachable", and continue do this until look on all vertexes

This code passes 6 of 20/40 in contest like a charm, and that's all
I cant see test data, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Some examples

```
4 4
1 2 4 1
2 4 4 4
1 4 3 2
1 2 3 2

aaaa(0, 0), Vertices that can reach all other vertices: (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), 
aaaa(3, 0), Vertices that can reach all other vertices: (3, 0), 
aaaa(0, 2), Vertices that can reach all other vertices: (0, 2), (2, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), 
aaaa(3, 2), Vertices that can reach all other vertices: (3, 2), (3, 3), 

4
```

```
4 6
1 1 2 5 3 10
1 0 3 4 6 8
1 2 12 -7 4 9
2 15 0 0 -5 -3

aaaa(0, 0), Vertices that can reach all other vertices: (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (5, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), 
aaaa(4, 0), Vertices that can reach all other vertices: (4, 0), 
aaaa(3, 2), Vertices that can reach all other vertices: (3, 2), (4, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), 
aaaa(4, 3), Vertices that can reach all other vertices: (4, 3), (5, 3), 

4
```

It's maybe not super easy to get into examples, but keep in mind, that we take ALL vertexes, and completely dont look on it on next step

Full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include<stack>
#include <queue>

#define DEBUG 1

const int MAXD = 100;
const int MAXN = MAXD*MAXD;
using namespace std;
int heights[MAXD][MAXD];
bool adjGraph[MAXN][MAXN];
int w, h;
int n;

int dx[] = {0, 1, 0, -1};
int dy[] = {1, 0, -1, 0};

int toOne(int x, int y){
    return y*w + x;
}

int oneToX(int o){
    return o % w;
}
int oneToY(int o){
    return o / w;
}

void generateAdj(){
    for (int y1 = 0; y1 < h; ++y1) {
        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < w; ++x1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                int x2 = x1 + dx[i];
                int y2 = y1 + dy[i];
                if(x2 < 0 || y2 < 0 || x2 >= w || y2 >= h) continue;
                adjGraph[toOne(x1, y1)][toOne(x2, y2)] = heights[y1][x1] >= heights[y2][x2];
            }
        }
    }
}
vector<int> dfs(int u, bool visited[]) {
    visited[u] = true;
    vector<int> reachable = {u};
    for (int v = 0; v < n; v++) {
        if (adjGraph[u][v] && !visited[v]) {
            vector<int> sub_reachable = dfs(v, visited);
            reachable.insert(reachable.end(), sub_reachable.begin(), sub_reachable.end());
        }
    }
    return reachable;
}

vector<int> get_reachable_vertices(int target) {
    bool visited[MAXN] = {false};
    vector<int> reachable = dfs(target, visited);
    queue<int> q;
    for (int u : reachable) {
        visited[u] = true;
        q.push(u);
    }
    while (!q.empty()) {
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for (int v = 0; v < n; v++) {
            if (adjGraph[v][u] && !visited[v]) {
                visited[v] = true;
                q.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
    vector<int> result;
    for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
        if (visited[u]) {
            result.push_back(u);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
bool isElementInVector(std::vector<int>& vec, int elem) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if (vec[i] == elem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    cin >> h >> w;
    n = w*h;
    if(n == 1){
        cout << 1;
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
            cin >> heights[i][j];
        }
    }
    #ifdef DEBUG
    cout << "w:" << w << ", h:" << h << "\n";
    for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
            int o = toOne(x, y);
            if(oneToX(o) != x || oneToY(o) != y) {
                cout << "ABOBA" << x <<", " << y;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
            cout << heights[y][x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    #endif
    generateAdj();

    #ifdef DEBUG
    for (int y1 = 0; y1 < h; ++y1) {
        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < w; ++x1) {
            for (int y2 = 0; y2 < h; ++y2) {
                for (int x2 = 0; x2 < w; ++x2) {
                    if(adjGraph[toOne(x1, y1)][toOne(x2, y2)]) {
                        cout << x1 << "," << y1 << " -> " << x2 << "," << y2 << " " << "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endif
    vector<int> reachable;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if(!isElementInVector(reachable, i)) {
            count++;
            vector<int> reachable2 = get_reachable_vertices(i);
            // Output the result
#ifdef DEBUG
            cout << "aaaa(" << oneToX(i) << ", " << oneToY(i) << "), ";
            cout << "Vertices that can reach all other vertices: ";
            for (int j : reachable2) {
                if(!isElementInVector(reachable, j)) {
                    cout << "(" << oneToX(j) << ", " << oneToY(j) << "), ";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
#endif
            reachable.insert(reachable.end(), reachable2.begin(), reachable2.end());
        }

    }
    cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tactical note: Before asking a question here you should at least use a debugger to locate where you first se a deviation between what you thing the program should have done and what it actually did. Usually that's enough information to allow you to fix the problem without any help, but when it isn't, it allows you to make a very targeted question and either get e a very quick answer or makes sure you're asked a really interesting question that will require an expert and is worth preserving for future programmers.

Comment: Doesn't look like you've tripped any of the usual mistakes, at least not with the basic inputs, so that means you now have the difficult job of finding test cases that result in failure. Test all of the edge cases from both sides, try to overflow buffers, generally be a complete jerk. Go out of your way to break the program. The judge is going to be a complete <expletive deleted>hole, so you have to be one as well to find the mistakes. Sometimes when you're stuck, you can employ [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing).

Comment: If it's some online testing program, is there a time limit? The implementation is perhaps inefficient, or even there might be a stack overflow recursing down the tree. Generate 100x100 data and see what happens.

Comment: I've just noticed there is an error in your second example - `(0, 0)` should be `(1, 1)`, I believe. (Also, negative numbers are not natural numbers, but we'll let that one slide)

Comment: No, the trouble not in a time limitation and so on. It's jsut a wrong answer on some test input, that I cant see and cant reproduce.

Comment: Thinking a little more about it, the algorithm should be something like While all nodes not visited: Choose lowest square as a trapdoor and mark it and all equal or higher adjacent squares as visited.

Comment: (on phone, so excuse poor formatting) try with the simplest 1x2 grid of `1 0`. Your code will probably return (0. 0) and maybe (1, 0) although the answer should be (1, 0) only.

Answer (score 1):

Check this input:

```
10 9
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
6 6 5 11 11 11 11 5 5
6 5 5 11 10 11 11 5 5
11 11 11 11 10 10 11 11 11
11 11 11 10 10 10 10 11 2
11 11 10 10 11 10 11 11 2
11 11 11 10 10 11 11 2 2
11 11 11 10 11 11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11 11 1 1 11 11
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 1 11
```

Your code prints 1, but it must be 6 for this case. So, try to debug the code and fix errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> dfs(int u, bool visited[]) {
    visited[u] = true;
    vector<int> reachable = {u};
    for (int v = 0; v < n; v++) {
        if (adjGraph[u][v] && !visited[v]) {
            vector<int> sub_reachable = dfs(v, visited);
            reachable.insert(reachable.end(), sub_reachable.begin(), sub_reachable.end());
        }
    }
    return reachable;
}
```

There is no need to iterate over every node in the graph!

Replace

```
for (int v = 0; v < n; v++) {
```

with

```
for( int v : reachable ) {
```

Comment: Not work anyway, and my basic code dont exceed the time limit

Comment: "Not work anyway"  Really?  That is your complete test report.  Error message, perhaps?  Unexpected result perhaps?  You want help, but that is all you can be bothered to write?

Comment: That's all I have

        № Result Resource Points.    
 1 ok 2ms / 296.00Kb -     
 2 ok 2ms / 292.00Kb -     
 3 ok 2ms / 296.00Kb -     
 4 ok 2ms / 420.00Kb -     
 5 ok 2ms / 548.00Kb -      
 6 wrong-answer 2ms / 680.00Kb -      

I'm try to test code my own data to catch the bug, with no success